# Display current date in application badge

Tags: ios, iphone

How do I show the correct day in a application badge. I have this but it doest display the right date.

```
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = NSDayCalendarUnit;
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? Doesn't seem so.

Comment: Its all I have tried do far @H2CO3

Comment: well, `applicationIconBadgeNumber` accepts a number only. You can't display the full date using it.

Comment: I just want to show the current day like "23" @H2CO3

Comment: in this case, you can obtain the day using `NSDateComponents`. I'll write an answer soon.

Comment: I suggest to edit it to reflect the answer and what finally ends been the real question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after you have improved your question, it seems that you want to display the number of the current day in the month as the app icon badge. You have to use `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents` for this:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comp = [cal components:NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:today];
NSInteger day = [comp day];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = day;
```

Comment: @Programmer... I did, it doesn't do what OP wants.

Comment: Argh, that's exactly what documentation stated! I was expecting some tricky way to do what iOS Calendar does or even more. Guys please!

Answer (score 0):

is not possible: it's only a (positive if I don't remember wrong) number. No letters, signs, spaces... Just one value.

Comment: It is indeed possible what OP is asking for, he just failed to ask his question properly.

Comment: actually he asked a completely different question... I suggest to edit it to reflect the answer and what finally ends been the real question...

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *formatString = [NSDateFormatter dateFormatFromTemplate:@"MMM d, yyyy h:mm" options:0 locale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:formatString];

NSString *todayString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
dateLabel.text = todayString;
```

The output: Feb 11, 2012 5:32:21 PM

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP wants to display the number of the day using the app icon badge, not inside the app on a label.

Answer (score 0):

First you can't display entire date in application badge icon.

However, if you want to display the day only, then have a look at below code.

```
NSDateComponents *comp = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = [comp weekday];
```

Cheers.